# AWS Step Functions - Invoke Another - All Built from Console

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I am testing out a flow where I use one Step Function to invoke another. The child State Machine will be used to invoke a lambda for data processing.

To bear this out, I am creating very simple objects via the web console, however, when attempting to run the parent process, I am getting the following error

```
User: arn:aws:sts::xxxxxxx:assumed-role/StepFunctions-ETL_POC-role-xxxx/step-functions-express-xxxx is not authorized to access this resource (Service: AWSStepFunctions; Status Code: 400; Error Code: AccessDeniedException;
```

I have played around by adding the Step Functions Full Access managed policy to the IAM role, but that didn't seem to do the trick.

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you update your question to include a sanitized version of your workflow definitions (ASL) as well as the policies for the execution role on your parent state machine?

Comment: Yes, I will later on today.  Thanks for reaching out.

Comment: Oh my gosh.  Thank you for asking me to walk through that process!  I could have sworn that I specified my child SFN's ARN, but it was the boiler plate setup; the ARN was generic and not pointing at my actual Child SFN.  Yikes.  Thanks again.

Comment: Cool, glad you were able to get it fixed!

Answer (score 2):

The issue was that the definition of the State Machine was using the default placeholder text.  I was attempting to do everything via the web console and never once thought to check if I had properly referenced the ARN.

This was only found after the first comment from Justin above.